# angularjs unnest ng-repeats into one query

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, unnest

```
<div ng-repeat="blub in filtered = (blubs | filter:tag)">
  <span ng-repeat="tag in blub.tags" class="tag-box">{{tag}}</span>
</div>
```

How can I unnest it into one query. I imagined it like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in blub.tags in filtered = (blubs | filter: tag)>{{tag}}</span>
```

Object blub has more than one tag, there are more than one blub objects.

EDIT:
Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mWjyryOsV5zZJisZzV3D
GOAL: Reduce 2 times ng-repeat into one ng-repeat which shows the same tags.

Comment: Please try and explain the issue a bit more, plunkrs / demos are always useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that situation I would recommend you first to create one collection instead of doing double looping.

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in getBlupList(filtered)" class="tag-box">{{tag}}</span>
```

Where getBlupList(filtered) are JS method. Some kind of reducer that creates one list instead of what you have. 
I dont know how your collection look like but personally for me for such situation the best solution is to use Underscore.js lib. "*.flatten()" or "*.pluck()"

Comment: Ok so there is no option doing it without a script? Because that makes all the nice filter functions of angular not useful anymore, if I anyways have to filter in the .js file before to get the list.

Comment: I dont know way to do it without script. And It you still can use filters. You can create one array or collection after getting data from server and add this variable to ng-repeat. It difficult to judge as I dont know how your collection look like.